# Lazy logging in C++

Tags: c++, logging, lazy-evaluation

Let's suppose that we have several levels of logging: trace, debug, info, error.
I was wondering if there is a way to write the following code:

```
enum log_level = {trace, debug, info, error};

log_level global_log_level = info;

void log(log_level level, string& message){
    if (level >= global_log_level){
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
    }
}

string create_message(){
    ...
}

log_level level = debug;
log (level, create_message());
```

without create_message being called if level is smaller that global_severity_level. Indeed, create_message can be quite long, and no matter what it creates a string. If there are a lot of "debug" logs, those ones can become a substantial overhead when running in non-debug mode.

I know it is possible to do so if the function "log" is a macro, calling create_message() only if severity > minimal_severity; but isn't there another way to do this without macros?

**EDIT**

In the above, I didn't specify create_message, because it could be anything, in particular:

```
log(level, "Created object " + my_object.getName());
```

In this case, is there a way to write log such that the full string is not created, in a relatively transparent way for the programmer calling log?

Many thanks

Comment: You could have `create_message()` check `global_log_level`.

Comment: Could you pass a `create_message` function into `log()` so `log()` will only build the expensive message if the level is appropriate?

Comment: Hello, I refer to an unspecified function create_message() because the message could come from anywhere, but it could be written on the fly, like log(level, "Object " + my_object.getName() + " has been created"); - in which case I cannot pass anything to create_message(), which is essentially operator+ between 2 strings... And neither can I pass this as a function into log...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to @sftrabbit, but as suggested by @ipc.

Use a template to avoid the std::function machinery, and the compiler may be able to inline this and thus it hopefully will end up being faster.

```
template< typename F >
void log(log_level level, F message_creator){
    if (level >= global_log_level){
        std::cout << message_creator() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 because I didn't have the time to make the change to my answer :D

Answer (score 6):

There are several alternatives. An interesting one is to pass `create_message` as a `std::function<std::string()>` and call it from within `log`:

```
void log(log_level level, std::function<std::string()> message_creator){
    if (level >= global_log_level){
        std::cout << message_creator() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Then you would call it like so:

```
log(level, create_message);
```

This can work with arbitrary expressions as arguments if you wrap them in a lambda:

```
log(level, [&](){ return "Created object " + my_object.getName(); });
```

If you really don't want to argument to be evaluated at all (as you've described in the comments), then you'll need to check the level outside of the call:

```
if (level >= global_log_level) {
  log(level, create_message());
}
```

Comment: Replace `[]` with `[&]`. Also what if create_message is any arbitrary function taking some arguments? It seems it is not enough to delay the function which creates the message; it also seems logical to delay the evaluation of function arguments themselves. How would the `log` function would know about those arguments is yet another problem.

Comment: Make `log` a template, then the compiler should be able to inline the lambda.

Comment: @Nawaz: in this case you wrap the call into a zero-parameter lambda.

Comment: Hi sftrabbit, many thanks for your answer; I am not yet faniliar (yet!) with std::function and lambdas, but this seems to do what I want!

Comment: @ipc, could you please elaborate?

Comment: A lambda is a lightweight type with it's own `operator()`. A `std::function` is a sophisticated type-erasure-monster that is expensive to create and expensive to call. If `log` takes a lambda object, the creation can be elided (since the compiler knows it's stateless) and the operator() can be inlined, which gives full speed. This is also useful for many algorithms in the stdlib.

Answer (score 1):

@sftrabbit answer is prefered. But just if you dont want to change log(), you can call it:

```
log (level, (level >= global_log_level)? create_message() : "");
```

Comment: Indeed, this works, didn't think about the ternary operator... But what if the caller of log is not aware of the internal of the logger, and of the existence of the variable global_log_level?

Comment: @GHL Then you turn this construct into a macro.  Kinda circular, eh ;-)

Comment: Yes indeed, but would do :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a macro

```
    #define log(level, message) { \
    if(level >= global_log_level) {\
    cout << message; }}
```

Now if you call

```
log(debug, create_message());
```

create_message will be called only if debug level is the desired one.

Comment: Just curious, why macro is a bad option for you?

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best solution before C++11.

Comment: What about params passing overhead? I like macros because they are cheap. This still should be faster then C++ 11 way. Even before C++ 11 you can still pass function pointer, but macro is better as for me.

Comment: I am just afraid of possible side effects of macros... and I find them quickly cumbersome to understand and debug. But to be honest, macros are a component of C+ I haven't used much yet.

Comment: You might have not used WTL :) macros aren't evil ;)